# How to decision 2-demension array has value?

Tags: asp.net

I am programming in C#,and define a 2-demension array:

```
holidays[1, 1] = "元旦";
holidays[2, 14] = "情人节";
holidays[3, 8] = "妇女节";
holidays[3, 12] = "植树节";
holidays[4, 1] = "愚人节";
holidays[5, 1] = "劳动节";
holidays[5, 4] = "青年节";
holidays[5, 12] = "护士节";
holidays[5, 14] = "母亲节";
holidays[5, 14] = "助残日";
```

How to judgement the value is null?

```
holidays[i,j] != string.Empty
```

has not effect in asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have space between the text you can alos use

```
!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(holidays[i, j])
```

According to documentation `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` evaluates to :-

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim().Length == 0;
```

The method [String.IsNullOrWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx):

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(holidays[i, j])
```